# service returns promise but cachingService not

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-services

I am calling the getWeeklyDates which is calling the cachingGlobalConfigurationService which is again calling the globalConfigurationService if the globalConfiguration data could not be found in the localstorage.

The code =>

```
return cachingGlobalConfigurationService.getGlobalConfiguration()
                   .then(function(response1){
```

works fine when the globalConfiguration is not cached yet because then I make the ajax call and return a promise.

But the above line of code with .then(function(response1) is undefined when my globalConfiguration can be found in the localStorage and just this is returned:

```
 else {
          return cachedGlobalConfiguration;
        }
```

I guess I can not use .then in this case but I would like.

How can I fix that?

**1**

```
this.getWeeklyDates= function (projectId, currentDate) {

        return cachingGlobalConfigurationService.getGlobalConfiguration()
               .then(function(response1){

        // do business logic
    });
```

**2**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test').service('cachingGlobalConfigurationService', function (localStorageService, globalConfigurationService) {
  this.getGlobalConfiguration = function () {

    var cachedGlobalConfiguration = localStorageService.get('globalConfiguration');
    if (!cachedGlobalConfiguration) {
      return globalConfigurationService.getGlobalConfiguration().then(
        function (globalConfiguration) {
          localStorageService.set('globalConfiguration', globalConfiguration);
          return globalConfiguration;
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
        });
    }
    else {
      return cachedGlobalConfiguration;
    }
  };

  this.saveGlobalConfiguration = function (globalConfiguration) {

    // TODO: Only save to local storage when service.save was successfully
    localStorageService.set('globalConfiguration', globalConfiguration);
    globalConfigurationService.saveGlobalConfiguration(globalConfiguration);
  }
});
```

**3**

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test').service('globalConfigurationService', function ($http) {
  this.getGlobalConfiguration = function () {

    // TODO get from db
    var path = 'scripts/model/globalConfiguration.json';
    return $http.get(path).then(function (response) {
      return response.data.globalConfiguration;
    });
  };

  this.saveGlobalConfiguration = function (globalConfiguration) {

    // TODO: save on db
    //var path = 'scripts/model/globalConfiguration.json';
    //return $http.post(path, globalConfiguration).then(function (response) {
    //  alert('global configuration was saved succesfully!');
    //});
  }
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can inject `$q` service and use [`$q.when`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to wrap the object while returning, so that way you are always returning a promise from your api (and just removed the redundant else). Also remember to reject the promise from catch callback of the promise (if required).

```
'use strict';
angular.module('test').service('cachingGlobalConfigurationService', function (localStorageService, globalConfigurationService, $q) {
  this.getGlobalConfiguration = function () {

    var cachedGlobalConfiguration = localStorageService.get('globalConfiguration');
    if (cachedGlobalConfiguration) {
        //Return a promise
        return $q.when(cachedGlobalConfiguration);
     }

     return globalConfigurationService.getGlobalConfiguration().then(
        function (globalConfiguration) {
          localStorageService.set('globalConfiguration', globalConfiguration);
          return globalConfiguration;
        },
        function (error) {
          console.log('error', error);
          return $q.reject(error); //<-- reject
        });
  };

  //....
});
```

> $q.when - Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a $q promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.